# PDF Invoice draw line between items

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf

I would like to have a line between each item purchased on the PDF invoice.

I went to Mage>Sales>Model>Order>Pdf>Items>Invoice>Default.php, made a local copy to not change the core items and added the following line after draw Tax:

```
/* Separator Line */
$page->setLineColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
$page->setLineWidth(0.5);
$page->drawLine(380, 30, 380, 40);
```

But it doesn't show up. Can someone let me know how the best way to do this.
Would be great, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is right, below code works for me

```
$page->setLineColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0)); //black
$page->setLineWidth(0.5);
$page->drawLine(10, 100, 600, 100);
```

I think you put it in wrong position.
Try to put it in different line/file, before or after, to see if it is printed.

Comment: Could you perhaps give me a gibt where too  put it

Comment: yes, try to put it in \app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php between $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order); and $page = end($pdf->pages); (line ~144)

Answer (score 9):

Your code is drawing a small vertical line towards the bottom of the page.

Here's one way to add the lines between each item line in Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php:

In getPDF() after `$this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);` add:

```
$page->setLineColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
$page->setLineWidth(0.5);
$page->drawLine(25, $this->y+12.5, 570, $this->y+12.5);
```

Comment: Thanks Luca S and Colm. Marked Luca S as solution as he was first. I found my problem I had the fooman extension to print orders and so I had to add this to: code/community/Fooman/EmailAttachements/Model/Order/Pdf/Order.php

Comment: this is a great solution.