# Magento2 PDF Invoice draw line between items

Tags: magento2

I need to add a line between items in Magento2 email Invoice template. I have referred below link for Magento1. How can I achieve same for Magento2

> [PDF Invoice draw line between items](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71732/pdf-invoice-draw-line-between-items)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `di.xml` override the file `vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" />
</config>
```

Copy function `getPdf` in your new file

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Order\Pdf;

class Invoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice
{
    public function getPdf($invoices = [])
    {
        //Old function code here
    }
}
```

find the line `$this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);`
After this you can add your code to draw the line:

```
$page->setLineColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
$page->setLineWidth(0.5);
$page->drawLine(25, $this->y+12.5, 570, $this->y+12.5);
```

I haven't tested this, but this should work.